# What type of object does "getResults()" return in docrine query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, marie

When I execute query using `find(id)` then it works OK.
But when I use `createQuery` method  like

`select u from User u where u.id = 1` then I get error that it is an array.

So I want to know if it always returns an array even if the result is 1?

I tried `getMaxResults(1)` but I get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for your question can be found in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql). It says

> The getResult() method returns an array of results. If you're querying for just one object, you can use the getSingleResult() method instead:

You should also check this [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Comment: Both links are stale (first not stale, but no description of getResult now)